# Conversion of query from oracle to mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle

How to convert the below query from oracle to mysql.

**ALTER table test 
  ADD CONSTRAINT TEST_FK FOREIGN KEY (id) 
  REFERENCES  another_table(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
  ENABLE NOVALIDATE;**

When i convert this I got the following error in mysql

**Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENABLE NOVALIDATE'**
Can any body please help me on this.

Thanks
SKP

Comment: Try without `ENABLE NOVALIDATE`

Answer (score 0):

This is standard syntax of adding a foreign key using alter query [Official](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] 
    FOREIGN KEY [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

in your query delete  `ENABLE NOVALIDATE`. Try this

```
ALTER table test 
  ADD CONSTRAINT TEST_FK 
      FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES another_table(id) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**Example** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

```
ALTER TABLE products
  ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_vendor(vdr_id) REFERENCES vendors(vdr_id)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```